# Current divider and capacitor

Tags: capacitor, current, resistors

I have this circuit which looks like a current divider but with an extra capacitor.
I want to know how Ia , Ib, Ic change as the capacitor begin to charge, i do know one thing after a time of 5 RC the capacitor will be about 99.5% and the first branch ( the one with the capacitor ) will be considered open, and we can consider the whole branch not there.
[image]

( the source is  a current source)

Comment: use circuit lab to evaluate.

Comment: How are you exciting the circuit? Do you apply a DC voltage, a DC current or something else to the + and - terminals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well \$I_c\$ will always be the sum of \$I_a\$ and \$I_b\$.

\$I_c = I_a + I_b \$

Assuming that the current supplied to the circuit is constant:

\$I_c\$ will be constant.

At the first instant, the capacitor is completely empty and acts like a short circuit. So the current is distributed like in a normal current divider. After the capacitor is fully charged, it acts as an open circuit and no current will flow through path B.

Now what happens between those two points:
The voltage across both paths must be the same (parallel circuit):

\$U(t) = I_a(t) * R_a\$

\$U(t) = I_b(t) * R_b + U_c(t)\$

\$U_c\$ is the voltage across the capacitor.

with that we end up with:

$$I_a(t) * R_a = I_b(t) * R_b + U_c(t)$$

Substituting the first statement this changes into:

$$(I_c(t)-I_b(t)) * R_a = I_b(t) * R_b + U_c(t)$$

Now we keep two things in mind: \$U_c(t) = \frac{Q_b(t)}{C}\$ and \$I(t)=\dot Q(t)\$ using this we end up with this lovely differential equation:

$$\frac{Q_b(t)}{C*(R_a+R_b)} + \dot Q_b(t) = I_c * R_a$$

Solved to (hopefully):

$$\large I_b(t) = I_c*\frac{R_a}{R_a+R_b}*e^{-\frac{t}{C*(R_a+R_b)}}$$

As for \$I_a(t)\$ well it has to add to \$I_b(t)\$ so that the result is constant.

$$\large I_a(t) = I_c (1-\frac{R_a}{R_a+R_b}*e^{-\frac{t}{C*(R_a+R_b)}})$$

Credits go mainly to [this German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC-Glied) article as I'm quite rusty with this kind of stuff.

---

Assuming that the voltage supplied to the circuit is constant:

\$I_a\$ will remain constant as it's just a simple resistor.

\$I_b\$ will behave like the charging current of a RC circuit. That is:
$$
\large
I_b(t) = \frac{U}{R}  e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}
$$
So together:
$$
\large
I_c(t) = \frac{U}{R}e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} + I_a
$$

Comment: Ia will remain constant if a constant voltage is attached across +/- terminals. Don't know if that is a valid assumption or not.

Comment: @mkeith that is a valid point, and I've added the assumption to my post. If an arbitrary voltage is applied, things get complicated.

Comment: I was thinking that a DC current might be applied since the OP used the term "current divider." In that case, as Ib decayed exponentially, Ib would have to increase by the same amount.

Comment: Oh, so a current source as input. Yeah that's another interesting suggestion. Let's wait for the response from @user28324.

Comment: sorry i didnt mention that, but this is indeed a dc current source, read the question wrong.
sorry again

Comment: Okay, maybe update your question accordingly.

Comment: @user28324 I've updated my answer to reflect the change in your question, which turned out to be much harder than I thought.

Comment: another question please, does the voltage across the capacitor approaches the voltage used in the current source, right?

Comment: @user28324 Yes, I was a bit sloppy on that part it seems. An ideal current source has no voltage limit. The voltage across the capacitor is given as Ic will all go trough Ra and the voltage across it (Ic * Ra) is the same as the voltage across Rb and C (it's a parallel circuit), as no current flows through Rb, it has no voltage across it, so all voltage must be across C. So the voltage must be Ic * Ra as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below schematic to do some attempts. I have created in case if you are not aware of tool!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJfT1j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>